# Проблема с таймером

Tags: таймер, java

----Класс с таймером----

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SomeTimer  {

public Timer time;

public SomeTimer() {

    time = new Timer(1000, new Tick());
    time.start();

}

//Не работает ActionListener но почему??
class Tick implements ActionListener {
    int i = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        i += 1;
        System.out.println(i);
        //time.stop();
    }
   }
 }
```

----Главный класс----

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SomeTimer();
}
}
```

При запуске не выводится ничего =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй поставить после `new SomeTimer();` `Thread.sleep(2000)`, а то у тебя не успевает сработать tick :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло :)